# How i get null, Didn't grab packet?

Tags: c++, networking, libpcap

I am following this tutorial: http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/section2.html

I executed this command: `gcc main.c -lpcap` and afterward `sudo ./a.out`
but I get this message: `Didn't grab packet`

In this code section, why is it null?

```
if(packet == NULL)
    {/* dinna work *sob* */
        printf("Didn't grab packet\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

This is the complete code:

```
/***************************************************
* file:     testpcap1.c
* Date:     Thu Mar 08 17:14:36 MST 2001 
* Author:   Martin Casado
* Location: LAX Airport (hehe)
*
* Simple single packet capture program
*****************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pcap.h> /* if this gives you an error try pcap/pcap.h */
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h> /* includes net/ethernet.h */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    char *dev; 
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t* descr;
    const u_char *packet;
    struct pcap_pkthdr hdr;     /* pcap.h */
    struct ether_header *eptr;  /* net/ethernet.h */

    u_char *ptr; /* printing out hardware header info */

    /* grab a device to peak into... */
    dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);

    if(dev == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",errbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("DEV: %s\n",dev);

    /* open the device for sniffing.

       pcap_t *pcap_open_live(char *device,int snaplen, int prmisc,int to_ms,
       char *ebuf)

       snaplen - maximum size of packets to capture in bytes
       promisc - set card in promiscuous mode?
       to_ms   - time to wait for packets in miliseconds before read
       times out
       errbuf  - if something happens, place error string here

       Note if you change "prmisc" param to anything other than zero, you will
       get all packets your device sees, whether they are intendeed for you or
       not!! Be sure you know the rules of the network you are running on
       before you set your card in promiscuous mode!!     */

    descr = pcap_open_live(dev,BUFSIZ,0,-1,errbuf);

    if(descr == NULL)
    {
        printf("pcap_open_live(): %s\n",errbuf);
        exit(1);
    }


    /*
       grab a packet from descr (yay!)                    
       u_char *pcap_next(pcap_t *p,struct pcap_pkthdr *h) 
       so just pass in the descriptor we got from         
       our call to pcap_open_live and an allocated        
       struct pcap_pkthdr                                 */

    packet = pcap_next(descr,&hdr);

    if(packet == NULL)
    {/* dinna work *sob* */
        printf("Didn't grab packet\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*  struct pcap_pkthdr {
        struct timeval ts;   time stamp 
        bpf_u_int32 caplen;  length of portion present 
        bpf_u_int32;         lebgth this packet (off wire) 
        }
     */

    printf("Grabbed packet of length %d\n",hdr.len);
    printf("Recieved at ..... %s\n",ctime((const time_t*)&hdr.ts.tv_sec)); 
    printf("Ethernet address length is %d\n",ETHER_HDR_LEN);

    /* lets start with the ether header... */
    eptr = (struct ether_header *) packet;

    /* Do a couple of checks to see what packet type we have..*/
    if (ntohs (eptr->ether_type) == ETHERTYPE_IP)
    {
        printf("Ethernet type hex:%x dec:%d is an IP packet\n",
                ntohs(eptr->ether_type),
                ntohs(eptr->ether_type));
    }else  if (ntohs (eptr->ether_type) == ETHERTYPE_ARP)
    {
        printf("Ethernet type hex:%x dec:%d is an ARP packet\n",
                ntohs(eptr->ether_type),
                ntohs(eptr->ether_type));
    }else {
        printf("Ethernet type %x not IP", ntohs(eptr->ether_type));
        exit(1);
    }

    /* copied from Steven's UNP */
    ptr = eptr->ether_dhost;
    i = ETHER_ADDR_LEN;
    printf(" Destination Address:  ");
    do{
        printf("%s%x",(i == ETHER_ADDR_LEN) ? " " : ":",*ptr++);
    }while(--i>0);
    printf("\n");

    ptr = eptr->ether_shost;
    i = ETHER_ADDR_LEN;
    printf(" Source Address:  ");
    do{
        printf("%s%x",(i == ETHER_ADDR_LEN) ? " " : ":",*ptr++);
    }while(--i>0);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All questions here must have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors, shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. This question must be [edit]ed, and all links and images removed and replaced with all relevant information, as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text. There's no reason why this one can't, either.

Comment: Odds are very good you don't need the last 50-or-so lines. The problem has already happened by then. The minimal part is often very important. More often than not, removing all of the noise around a problem allows you to see and fix the problem without any help.

Comment: @user4581301 but will not  be reproducible my example

Comment: Is the question not, "Why do I get `NULL` at point x in code?" The code after that point should be irrelevant, and if it isn't, you've learned something really neat about the behaviour of the program. The [man page for `pcap_next`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_next) says you could be having a timeout. The [documentation I've seen for `pcap_open_live`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_open_live) doesn't say anything about what happens if you pass -1 in for `to_ms`. You could be timing out instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user4581301 is entirely correct here.

Do *not* pass -1 as the timeout argument to `pcap_open_live()`; there is no guarantee that this will do anything useful.  Pick a value such as 1000 (for a 1-second timeout; that's the traditional tcpdump value) or 100 (for a .1-second timeout, which will deliver packets more quickly if they're arriving at a low rate).

Do *not* give up if `pcap_next()` returns NULL; that could just mean that 1) the timeout occurs even if *no* packets have arrived and 2) no packets arrived during the timeout period.  If you want to distinguish between timeouts and errors, you have to use `pcap_next_ex()`.